# Why not clear datagridview?? and how to Clear datagridView?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I want to clear rows in datagridView , but every code is not working i searched it is bug?? my code below

```
  private DataSet modelDS = null;
  modelDS = db.getModelList();

 /* 
  class db{
     private DataSet ds = null;
    public db(){
       ds = new DataSet();
       setModelList();
     }
    private void setModelList(){
       //after DB Query
       oda.Fill(ds);  
     }
    public DataSet getModelList(){
       retrun ds;
    }
   }

  */

 dataGridView18.DataSource = modelDS.Tables[0];

  //row list delete or add  by user in only dataGridView
  //users can not save them and they click only reload button

private void button1_Click (object sender , EventArgs e){
    //reload button envent
    //after clearing DataGridView ,dataSource reloaded
    datagridView18.DataSource = null (not working)

    datagridView18.Rows.clear() (not working)
    
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)datagridview18.DataSource
    dt.Clear() or dt.Rows.Clear() (not working)
    
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in datagrdiview18.Rows)
    datagridView18.Rows.Remove(row) (not working)
    
    dataGridView18.DataSource =  modelDS.Tables[0];

}
```

after reload , contents in dataGridView is not showing modelDS.Tables's contents it is showing edited contents by user!!

i think datagridview should be shown datatable's contents because datasource be setted null and reload datatable. but it is not show datatable's contents

what is the reason?? and how to fix it?? thanks

Comment: This: `datagridView18.DataSource = null` of course clears the DataGridView completely. After that, what do you want to do? Set back the same DataSource as before? The one that has been modified? Do you mean to re-query the data to discard any User input? Is the User input meaningful in any way?

Comment: Can you write a small amount of code that reproduces the issue?  It's unclear what you're trying to do and what the problem is.  I'm guessing somewhere you are either submitting to database or grabbing the table again due to this line I don't see elsewhere?  `modelDS = db.getModelList();`

Comment: This code is just test about datagridview control. anyway Even if the user modified list of datagridview, if datasource is reload, Shouldn't the original lists be displayed?  datagridView display user's modified list. even though clear and is setted null datasouce  before datasource is reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> list in dataGridView is not showing modelDS.Tables's list it is showing edited list by user!!

Sounds like you're not understanding that data binding is two way. Any changes the user makes are persisted into the datatable. This is typically what we want when we use databinding. Imagine you have this form code:

```
class Form1{

  private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  public Form1(){
    InitializeComponenent();

    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Rows.Add("John");
    

  }

  private void unbindButton_Click(...){
    someDataGridView.DataSource = null;
  }
  
  private void bindButton_Click(...){
    someDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
  }
  
  private void show00Button_Click(...){
    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()); 
  }
}
```

- You run the app
- you click BIND button
- dgv DataSource is set
- you see John
- you edit to Mary
- data table dt is altered. Yes, actually the contents of the datatable are changed.
- you click UNBIND
- you click SHOW00, MessageBox saying "mary" appears
- you click BIND, "Mary" appears in grid
- it is because datatable is edited and contains Mary

If you want the original table not to be edited, duplicate it:

```
someDataGridView.DataSource = originalDataTable.Copy();
```

Comment: According your post, it show mary but i set null of datasource in my case and i reload datatable to datasource. see my post
So, i don't understand why datagridview not show list of datatable.

Comment: What do you mean by "list of datatable" ?

Comment: I think datagridview should be shown datatable's contents because datasource be setted null and reload datatable.  isn't it?

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. A datagridview shows the contents of a datatable. You cannot set the DataSource of a DGV to be a DataSet (a collection of datatables) and a DGV will never show "a list of datatables" unless you write code that does it.

Comment: Sorry, i misrepresented the contents of the datatable as a list. my question is that Even though I reloaded the datatable to datasource , why do I keep showing the modifications made by the user in dgv?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
datagridView18.DataSource = null
```

Then After

```
datagridView18.DataBind()
```

Comment: Not sure the datagridview the OP is talking about has a DataBind method

Comment: There's no `DataBind()` method in a DataGridView.